# Reading whatsapp notifications using a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make an app which reads the message received by WhatsApp and show that message on my Flutter App. I was able to use a package: https://pub.dev/packages/notifications#-readme-tab-
This pacakge only tells me that I have received a message but cant be used to see the message received.

Please note I am trying to do this in Flutter.